# Dependency injection issue with services and filter

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am new to angularjs and have created three apps based on the angularjs tutorial.

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

The apps are `documentprofileApp`, `machineorderApp` and `regionresourceApp`.  I've setup services for each that reside in the `core` folder.  Also in the core folder is a filter named `checkmark`.

To use `checkmark` you enter `'core'` as a dependency in the app.module.  **If I want to use the `checkmark` in the `documentprofileApp` I have to add script references to the `machineorder` and `regionresource` services files or I get an injection error.**

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=documentprofileApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.7.7%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dcore%26p1%3D%255B%2524injector%253Amodulerr%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.7.7%252F%2524injector%252Fmodulerr%253Fp0%253Dcore.machineorder...

**documentprofileApp doesn't use those services so I would prefer not to have to have references to them.**

My question is, should I create the services outside of the core folder or have I set something up incorrectly in how the dependencies are referenced in the various modules.

Instead of referencing 'core' as a dependency I tried referencing 'core.checkmark' similar to how the services are referenced (core.document, core.machineorder, etc).  This doesn't work.

I went back to the tutorial and made sure I understood and followed how they had set it up there.  Since this is an introductory tutorial it might just be that it is simplified for its purpose and I need to seek other sources to learn how to setup my project for multiple applications.

Folder structure:

[FolderStructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zRL3.png)

[image]

core.module:

```
 angular.module('core', [
 'core.document', 
 'core.organization', 
 'core.department', 
 'core.machineorder', 
 'core.regionresource', 
 'core.region']);
```

app.module:

```
 angular.module('documentprofileApp', [
     'ngAnimate',
     'ngRoute',
     'core',
     'documentDetail',
     'documentList'
 ]);

 angular.module('machineorderApp', [
     'ngAnimate',
     'ngRoute',
     'ngCookies',
     'thatisuday.dropzone',
     'machineorderDetail',
     'machineorderList'
 ]);

angular.module('regionresourceApp', [
     'ngAnimate',
     'ngRoute',
     'regionresourceDetail',
     'regionresourceList'
 ]);
```

document-list.module:

```
 angular.module('documentList', ['core.document']);
```

layout template:

```
 <head>
     <title>Document Profiles</title>
     @Styles.Render("~/bundle/machineOrderFileCommonCss")
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundle/machineOrderFileCommonJs")
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundle/documentProfileJs")
     <script src="/app/core/machineorder/machineorder.module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="/app/core/machineorder/machineorder.service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="/app/core/regionresource/regionresource.module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="/app/core/regionresource/regionresource.service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
 <div ng-app="documentprofileApp">
     <div class="view-container">
         <div ng-view class="view-frame"></div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Bundles:

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundle/machineOrderFileCommonJs").Include(
            "~/Scripts/common.js",
            "~/Scripts/angular.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/angular-animate.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/angular-resource.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/angular-route.js",
            "~/Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/angular-messages.min.js",
            "~/app/app.module.js",
            "~/app/app.config.js",
            "~/app/core/core.module.js"
            ));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundle/machineOrderFileJs").Include(
            "~/Scripts/angular-cookies.min.js",
            "~/Code/FileManagement/dropzone.js",
            "~/Scripts/ng-dropzone.js",
            "~/app/core/machineorder/machineorder.module.js",
            "~/app/core/machineorder/machineorder.service.js",
            "~/app/machineorder-list/machineorder-list.module.js",
            "~/app/machineorder-list/machineorder-list.component.js",
            "~/app/machineorder-detail/machineorder-detail.module.js",
            "~/app/machineorder-detail/machineorder-detail.component.js"
            ));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundle/documentProfileJs").Include(
            "~/app/core/checkmark/checkmark.filter.js",
            "~/app/core/document/document.module.js",
            "~/app/core/document/document.service.js",
            "~/app/core/organization/organization.module.js",
            "~/app/core/organization/organization.service.js",
            "~/app/core/department/department.module.js",
            "~/app/core/department/department.service.js",
            "~/app/document-list/document-list.module.js",
            "~/app/document-list/document-list.component.js",
            "~/app/document-detail/document-detail.module.js",
            "~/app/document-detail/document-detail.component.js"
            ));
```

Thank you in advance to anyone who can offer any insight as to why the service files must be linked.

Comment: Try reading [Angular Structure Guide](https://github.com/kevinvanhove/angular-structure-styleguide/blob/master/README.md) or [JohnPapa: Angular 1 Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#angular-1-style-guide).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message decodes as follows:

> Failed to instantiate module `documentprofileApp` due to:
>   [$injector:modulerr] [http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=c...](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=core&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.7.7%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dcore.machineorder).
>
> Failed to instantiate module `core` due to:
>   [$injector:modulerr] [http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=c...](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=core.machineorder)
>
> Failed to instantiate module `core.machineorder` due to:
>   {1}

A common reason why the module fails to load is that you've forgotten to include the file with the defined module or that the file couldn't be loaded.

Either you did not include those files, or the module is not named `"core.machineorder"`.